# Cauchy sequence manipulation

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_k)_k\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Is $(e^{1/x_k})_k$ a Cauchy sequence as well? I am not sure how to approach this question.

Comment: What do you need to prove about $e^{1/x_k}$ in order to show that it is a Cauchy sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in $\mathbb{R}$, a sequence converges iff the sequence is Cauchy. So since $(x_k)_k$ is Cauchy, $(x_k)_k$ converges to some $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

- If $x\neq 0$, by continuity, $(e^{1/x_k})_k$ converges to $e^{1/x}$, so that $(e^{1/x_k})_k$ is Cauchy.
- If $x=0$, $1/x_k\,\rightarrow_k\infty$, so there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $k\geq N$, $$|x_{k+1}-x_k|\geq \varepsilon,$$
  so that $(1/x_k)_k$ is not Cauchy and therefore neither $(e^{1/x_k})_k$.

Comment: Unless $x_k\to 0$, for example for $x_k=\frac{1}{k}$ we get the sequence $\{e^k\}$ which is clearly not Cauchy.

Comment: But what if lets say x_k=1/n for every n in natural numbers which is convergent so it is Cauchy. Then wouldn't that make the sequence of e^1/x_k to e^n which in turn wouldn't be convergent hence, not Cauchy?

Comment: @Tommy1234 yes indeed